# How to use the ID of one XML file in another XML in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-8

I have two xml files and my module folder name is `roommanager`

**main.xml**

```
<menuitem id="main" name="Request"/>
```

**second.xml**

```
<menuitem id="dashboard-main" name="Dashboards" parent="roommanger.main" sequence="1" action="some_action"/>
```

When i used like this it is showing error as external id not found. If I used main as a value of parent option, then also it is showing me an error.

Can anybody help me, how to specify the ID in one XML file in another parent attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The external ID is the nombre of the module plus the id.

"ModuleName.main", not the models name.

Anyway if we are speaking about the same module, you dont need the roommanager or the module name, main should be enough.

Comment: I tried in both way, i.e, specified id with foldername.ID and simply ID in parent attribute. But both giving external id not found exception.  My xml files are in same module.

Comment: it may be the order in the __openerp__ file of the xmls then, put the main first. Do this test: Comment the xml of the child in the __openerp__ file and install it witout it, then uncomment it and refresh the module